# ¿Cómo se leería esta condición?

Tags: php

¿Me podrían explicar el ciclo que ocurre en este código?, la condición que se usa en el `while` no me queda muy clara:

```
$Lista1 = array("nombre" => "Alejandro", 
                "apellido" => "rivas",
                "nacionalidad" => "xxxx",
                "estado_civil" => "xxxx",
               );

while(list($key,$value) = each($Lista1)){
    echo "$key => $value\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función [**each**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.each.php) devuelve el par clave valor en formato de arreglo, cada vez que lo hace aumenta el puntero del arreglo.

```
each($Lista1)
```

devuelve la primera vez:

```
Array(
    [1] => Alejandro
    [value] => Alejandro
    [0] => nombre
    [key] => nombre
)
```

luego la segunda devuelve los datos del elemento 2, etc.

Esto es asignado a las variables `$key` y `$value` por medio de [**list**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.list.php).

```
list($key,$value) = each($Lista1);
```

es como decir:

```
// este es un ejemplo para entender el concepto, esto da error.
list($key,$value) = array("nombre" => "Alejandro");

// pero es asi como list recibe el arreglo
list($key,$value) = array(0 => "nombre", 1 => "Alejandro");
```

> **list()** solo funciona con arrays numéricos y supone que los índices numéricos empiezan en 0.

Entonces dentro del while, `$key` es asignado a la clave del elemento y `$value` a el valor, esto para cada elemento. Entonces el ciclo se repite hasta que no hay mas elementos.

```
// código equivalente a cuando no hay mas elementos
while(list($key, $value) = false){
    // ...
}
```

> Si el puntero interno del array apunta al final del contenido de array, **each()** devuelve **FALSE**.

Esto se puede lograr también con [**foreach**](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
foreach ($Lista1 as $key => $value){
    echo "$key => $value\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$Lista1` es un array asociativo, es decir, un array en el que los índices son cadenas en lugar de números. Se podría ver como un array de duplas clave-valor. Ese array tiene cuatro valores (clave "nombre" con valor "Alejandro", clave "apellido" con valor "rivas", etc.)

El `while` lo que hace es que atraviesa cada elemento de ese array (con [`each`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.each.php)  para separar clave y valor) y usa [`list`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.list.php) en dos variables (`$key` y `$value` respectivamente) y poder usarlas individualmente. De este modo no se pierde el valor de la clave, que sí se perdería si se utilizara otro método como `foreach ... as ...`).